# web app won't load , no errors in apache2's error log

Tags: php, linux, apache, codeigniter, ubuntu

I have a codeigniter web application that's running in a production environment.  I am trying to set up a new development box and have copied all files over and am trying to get it up and running. So far, it's been a no go!. 
When I submit the page/request for data... I get back a 200 ... but the json data doesn't appear on the page.

**Code**

Here's the "widgets" controller code that's being executed:

```
public function getlocations()
{
    echo("made it here");
    exit;
    $data = $this->rh_model->get_locations();
    header ('Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8');
    echo json_encode($data);    
   // $this->output->enable_profiler(TRUE);
}//getlocations
```

**What I've tried so far**

1. As you can see, I've been playing around with the code to see if the method is even called.
2. The model method "get_locations" calls a database and requests data.  I've made sure from a command prompt that I can connect to the database manually using the same credentials that the application uses - as defined in my /var/www/html/rhAPI/application/config/database.php file.
3. Here's what /var/log/apache2/access.log shows:

> 127.0.0.1 - - [10/Dec/2014:11:16:13 -0500] "GET /rhAPI/index.php/widgets/getlocations HTTP/1.1" 200 225 "-"
>   "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like
>   Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.71 Safari/537.36"
>   127.0.0.1 - - [10/Dec/2014:11:16:28 -0500] "GET /rhAPI/index.php/widgets/getlocations HTTP/1.1" 200 225 "-"
>   "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:34.0) Gecko/20100101
>   Firefox/34.0"

4. There's nothing in the apache2 error log.
5. The Networking section in my browser's debug tool shows a 200 OK Status Code in the "Headers" tab, but the Response tab is empty.
6. File permissions.  I've made sure all my folders have 755 and the files are 644.  I don't think it's a permissions issue because when I purposely set the permissions incorrectly, the permissions errors do show up on the web page. My php.ini settings are set to display errors, for ALL error messages.

I'm not sure what else I can check. 
Any suggestions would be appreciated.

**EDIT 1**

I just tried this test on the development box:

1. create a new folder under /var/www/html called "test"
2. create a new php file called phpinfo.php with the following code:
3. tried to navigate to localhost/test/phpinfo.php  but I'm not getting anything there either.

Now I'm suspecting apache2 set up... checking...

**EDIT 2**

I've added the following entries to the constructor in the ***model***

```
      public function __construct()
      {
          echo("in the constructor");
          parent::__construct();
          $this->load->database();
          echo("loaded");
      }
```

The first debug statement is printed but the second one is not. 
Here's what I have in database.php:

```
$active_group = 'default';
$active_record = TRUE;

$db['default']['hostname'] = 'localhost';
$db['default']['username'] = 'root';
$db['default']['password'] = 'test1234';
$db['default']['database'] = 'testdb';
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysql';
$db['default']['dbprefix'] = '';
$db['default']['pconnect'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['cachedir'] = '';
$db['default']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['default']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
$db['default']['swap_pre'] = '';
$db['default']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['stricton'] = FALSE;
```

And here's what I do via command line to test that the database connectivity is working:

```
me@medev:/var/www/html/rhAPI/application/models$ mysql -u root -p testdb
Enter password: 
Reading table information for completion of table and column names
You can turn off this feature to get a quicker startup with -A

Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 53
Server version: 5.6.19-1~exp1ubuntu2 (Ubuntu)

Copyright (c) 2000, 2014, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql>
```

Comment: What happens if you remove the exit;

Comment: Try turning on CI logging and see if that throws up any issues (set the "threshold" for logging in `application/config/config.php`)

Comment: @Craig that doesn't seem to make a difference

Comment: @Tim, I've set $config['log_threshold'] to 1... but nothing

Comment: @dot Can you access the default welcome controller that comes with CI?

Comment: @Tim, yes, when I do localhost/rhAPI/index.php - the welcome to codeigniter page comes up... interesting... maybe it's not a php config problem

Comment: @dot could you update your code to show the whole controller? Also, does the welcome page show when you go to `localhost/rhAPI/index.php/welcome` ?

Comment: What do your error logs show?  Apache usually stores those in a different place.

Comment: @Tim, localhost/rhAPI/index.php/welcome works too...Here's the code: http://pastebin.com/CXY2ft6h

Comment: @Robert, i've already checked the /var/logs/apache2/error.log.  There's nothing there.

Comment: @dot Everything looks ok. Are you trying to access it through `localhost/rhAPI/index.php/devices/getlocations`? As you are not accessing your model, try commenting that out of the __construct

Comment: @Tim, good suggestion.  I am actually trying to access the model... but I think we've hit on something.  Please check out my edit 2.

Comment: @dot does the database you are trying to connect to exist?

Comment: @Tim, yes, it does.  In Edit 2, i've tried to show how I can connect via command line to the database in question.  I've also added a call to parent::__construct(); before I call the load database method. but that didn't work either.

Comment: @Tim, I think I'm going to open another question and focus on the fact that I can't even get a basic PHPINFO(); to print out on this new server. (please see Edit 1 for details)

Comment: Your php is not linked up to apache. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ApacheMySQLPHP

Comment: @NicholasYoung I've added extension=mysql.so in the php.ini file... and that's helped the php test page.  now i'm struggling with enabling php short tags, I've set short_open_tag=On in php.ini and restarted but <? ?> still doesn't work. Having said that, it appears that all my CI files start with <?php so technically, i should be ok...

Answer (score 1):

I'm an idiot.  I was missing the php5 mysql driver / package on this new server. 
I had to :

```
sudo apt-get install php5-mysql
sudo service apache2 restart
```

And all my problems have gone away.  Sorry for the noise.